# Why am I getting error message "Sorry you are not using tor"?

Tags: linux, firefox, tor

Rather blindly I did the following steps from a Linux desktop:
Step 1: installed Tor using apt-get
Step 2: Added Tor extension to Firefox
Step 3: In FF, Open in Tor Browser
Step 4: Downloaded and installed the ["one last step"](http://moz-extension://0c0debf8-eb0d-4b40-a5de-fc2e803b676d/data/helper/index.html) 
Step 5: Check connection says "Native client is 0.6.7"
Step 6: https://check.torproject.org/ says I am not in tor

Based on some online advice in the terminal (don't know what to make of it):

```
$ sudo service tor stop
$ tor
Apr 13 21:22:29.494 [notice] Tor 0.2.9.14 running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2g and Zlib 1.2.8.
Apr 13 21:22:29.494 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Apr 13 21:22:29.494 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Apr 13 21:22:29.497 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Apr 13 21:22:29.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Apr 13 21:22:30.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server
Apr 13 21:22:30.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server
Apr 13 21:22:31.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection
Apr 13 21:22:31.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus
Apr 13 21:22:31.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus
Apr 13 21:22:32.000 [notice] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus.
^[[AApr 13 21:22:33.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 40%: Loading authority key certs
^[[AApr 13 21:22:33.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 45%: Asking for relay descriptors
Apr 13 21:22:33.000 [notice] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We need more microdescriptors: we have 0/6362, and can only build 0% of likely paths. (We have 0% of guards bw, 0% of midpoint bw, and 0% of exit bw = 0% of path bw.)
Apr 13 21:22:33.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 50%: Loading relay descriptors
Apr 13 21:22:35.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 55%: Loading relay descriptors
Apr 13 21:22:35.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 61%: Loading relay descriptors
Apr 13 21:22:36.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 71%: Loading relay descriptors
Apr 13 21:22:36.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
Apr 13 21:22:36.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
Apr 13 21:22:37.000 [notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
Apr 13 21:22:37.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
^CApr 13 21:28:58.000 [notice] Interrupt: exiting cleanly.
```

[image]

What steps did I miss/ what further steps can I take to troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: Terminal indicates you successfully connected to the TOR network

Comment: Be aware that Tor has their own Stackexchange as well :) stay safe on Tor!

Comment: If you want to browse the darknet and the clearnet over Tor exit node, you just need to use Tor Browser, it comes with its own Tor bundled and is superior to vanilla Firefox in terms of privacy/anonymity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd do better to get the Tor Browser Bundle directly from the Tor project. It is portable. It is optimized for the purpose. It is well maintained. It is EASY and much harder to screw up. You can STILL add extensions & modify settings if you want, but at least you'll be starting from a sound place. Be careful modifying it though. I wouldn't trust any distro's repo version of tor to be up to date, and I wouldn't trust a browser extension. The tor people know what they are doing. Tinkering with other configurations is really for experts.